# What is difference between @Reference & getScriptHelper() in CQ?

Tags: aem

I am looking into some CQ code and found that services can be obtained using either

```
@Reference

private JCRService searchService;
```

OR

```
TaxonomyService taxonomyService = getScriptHelper()
            .getService(TaxonomyService.class);
```

What is the difference betwen two approaches and which one is better?

Answer (score 1):

The ScriptHelper is meant to give you access to OSGi services from the presentation layer (jsp, sightly, etc), if you are in a Component, @Reference is the best way to get a reference to a service.

It also has several advantages, since it will be injected by the Service Component Runtime (SCR). for example:

- Define if the reference is static or dynamic
- You can be certain your component wont activate if its dependencies are not available
- Define the cardinality of the reference
- use a filter to get specific target , to get specific instance, for example.

Comment: Thanks, So SlingScriptHelper is available in UI layer which can be had using sling variable and @Reference is used in Java backend using SCR notations.